# From html mail body invoke bean's method

Tags: java, html, jsf-2

In my application the requirement is in mail body there have a html button which 
    is inside a form , from here by button click I have to invoke controller's method.
    I want to send a string parameter as a hidden value.I think I have done somthing wrong
    when I click on mail body's button one new tab is being open containg the action url,
    but I want to do action on parent frame the `target="_self"` not working here.bydefault
    `target="_blank"` is being set.
    Anyone can help how it can be implemented?
    This is mimeMessage/mail body:

```
text.append("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
text.append("<body>");
text.append("<form name=\"aproveDeny\" method=\"post\" target=\"_self\" action=\"http://localhost:8080/ActivityDatabase/req/AproveReq.xhtml\">");
text.append("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Aprove\" name=\"aproveDeny:aprove\" id=\"aproveDeny:aprove\">");
text.append("<input id=\"aproveDeny:hid1\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"aproveDeny:hid1\" value=\""+ActivityId+"\">");
text.append("</form>");
text.append("</body>");
text.append("</html>");
```

In background I want to invoke this AproveReq.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="aproveDeny">
    <h:commandButton id="aprove" value="Aprove" action="#{aproveOrDenyController.aproveActivityEntryReq}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="hid1" value="#{aproveOrDenyController.hiden}" /> 
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

The backing bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "aproveOrDenyController")
@RequestScoped
public class AproveOrDenyController implements Serializable{
    private String hiden;
    public void aproveActivityEntryReq(){ 
        System.out.println("------------"+this.hiden);
    }
    //getters setters hiden..
}
```

Any pointer will be very helpful to me.